# Obtaining a formula for prediction limits in a linear model (i.e.: prediction intervals)

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, prediction-interval

Let's take the following example:

```
set.seed(342)
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
y <- x1+x2 + 2*x1*x2 + rnorm(100)
fit <- lm(y~x1*x2)
```

This creates a model of y based on x1 and x2, using a OLS regression.  If we wish to predict y for a given x_vec we could simply use the formula we get from the `summary(fit)`.

However, what if we want to predict the lower and upper predictions of y? (for a given confidence level).

How then would we build the formula?

Comment: The *Confidence Interval on New Observations* section of [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20110719124646/http://www.weibull.com/DOEWeb/confidence_intervals_in_multiple_linear_regression.htm) may help.

Comment: @Tal Sorry, but it's not really clear to me what you actually mean by "predict the lower and upper predictions of y". Does it have something to do with prediction or tolerance bands?

Comment: @Tal - a couple of queries. When you say " .. y based on x1 and x2, using a OLS regression." , you mean your create a linear model and _estimate parameters using OLS_. Am I right? and @chl's question -- do you want to predict the lower and upper bounds for the prediction interval?

Comment: @chl, sorry for not being more clear.  I am looking for two formulas that will give an interval for that will "catch" the "real" value of y 95% of the time.  I feel how I'm using definitions for the CI for the mean, when there is probably some other term I should be using, sorry about that...

Comment: @suncoolsu - yes and yes.

Comment: Than you need the formula I suggested above. I will re-post it as an answer.

Comment: See the formula in the *Confidence Interval on New Observations* section (prediction interval) of http://www.weibull.com/DOEWeb/confidence_intervals_in_multiple_linear_regression.htm [(permalink)](http://www.webcitation.org/5xonEjGdb).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You will need matrix arithmetic. I'm not sure how Excel will go with that. Anyway, here are the details.

Suppose your regression is written as $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{e}$.

Let $\mathbf{X}^*$ be a row vector containing the values of the predictors for the forecasts (in the same format as $\mathbf{X}$). Then the forecast is given by
$$
\hat{y} = \mathbf{X}^*\hat{\mathbf{\beta}} = \mathbf{X}^*(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Y}
$$
with an associated variance
$$
\sigma^2 \left[1 + \mathbf{X}^* (\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1} (\mathbf{X}^*)'\right].
$$
Then a 95% prediction interval can be calculated (assuming normally distributed errors) as
$$
\hat{y} \pm 1.96 \hat{\sigma} \sqrt{1 + \mathbf{X}^* (\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1} (\mathbf{X}^*)'}.
$$
This takes account of the uncertainty due to the error term $e$ and the uncertainty in the coefficient estimates. However, it ignores any errors in $\mathbf{X}^*$. So if the future values of the predictors are uncertain, then the prediction interval calculated using this expression will be too narrow.

Comment: +1, excellent answer. I should note though, that regression model always estimates conditional expectation, so it is as good as its regressors are. So the last comment although is very good, it is not strictly necessary, since if you build regression model you must trust the regressors.

Comment: why the 1 comes up in the formula? We have $\hat{y}=X^*\beta+X^*(X'X)^{-1}X'e$. Then $var \hat{y}=var X^*(X'X)^{-1}X'e=\sigma^2X^*(X'X)^{-1}(X^*)'$?

Comment: The 1 is for prediction intervals. Leave it off for confidence intervals. Var($\hat{y}$) relates to confidence intervals.

Comment: @RobHyndman thank you for your excelent answer (one year ago ;)) however, am I missing something or is the term in the square root $N \times N$?

Comment: @Seb. $X^*$ is a row vector, so the term is scalar.

Comment: @RobHyndman yes of course! sorry - i didn't realize

Comment: Hi, when calculating the prediction & confidence intervals, should we use the square root of variance $\sqrt{Var{(\hat{y})}}$ to multiply with the critical value or use the standard error   $\frac{\sqrt{Var{(\hat{y})}}}{\sqrt{n}}$ to multiply with the critical value?

Comment: I did not provide the variance of y-hat, but the **forecast variance**.

Comment: if the errors are normally distributed then we can say that $y$ is normally distributed. How can we say that $\hat{y}$ is also normally distributed. For example here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164114/show-confidence-limits-and-prediction-limits-in-scatter-plot/63560689#63560689) the top answer uses t-distribution

Answer (score 9):

Are you by chance after the different types of prediction intervals? The `predict.lm` manual page has

```
 ## S3 method for class 'lm'
 predict(object, newdata, se.fit = FALSE, scale = NULL, df = Inf, 
         interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"),
         level = 0.95, type = c("response", "terms"),
         terms = NULL, na.action = na.pass,
         pred.var = res.var/weights, weights = 1, ...)
```

and

> Setting
>   ‘intervals’ specifies computation of confidence or prediction
>   (tolerance) intervals at the specified ‘level’, sometimes referred
>   to as narrow vs. wide intervals.

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Hi Dirk, that is indeed what I wish to find, but I want the upper and lower bonds to be in the form of a *formula* (so to later implement in some low form of statistical software, for example, excel...)

Comment: p.s: I now see that there was an edit to the title of my question that might had led you to think I was asking about predict.lm interval parameter (which I am not)  :)

Comment: You are abusing terminology here.  Excel is not statistical software.

Comment: You're right, my bid, how about "a spreadsheet application" ?

Comment: I can live with that; it calls the devil by its name ;-)

Answer (score 7):

@Tal: Might I suggest [Kutner et al](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007310874X) as a fabulous source for linear models.

There is the distinction between

1. a prediction of $Y$ from an individual new observation $X_{vec}$,
2. the expected value of a $Y$ conditioned on $X_{vec}$, $E(Y|X_{vec})$ and
3. $Y$ from several instances of $x_{vec}$

They are all covered in detail in the text.

I think you are looking for the formula for the confidence interval around $E(Y|X_{vec})$ and that is $\hat{Y} \pm t_{1-\alpha/2}s_{\hat{Y}}$ where $t$ has $n-2$ d.f. and $s_{\hat{Y}}$ is the standard error of $\hat{Y}$, $\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n} +(X_{vec}-\bar{X})^{2}\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\sum(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}}$

Comment: (+1) for making the distinction.  However, I believe the OP is asking for (1), not (2) (and I have edited the question's title accordingly).  Also note that your formula appears to assume the regression depends only on one variable.