Prediction bands for weighted linear regression
For a linear regression of $x_i, y_i,$ we know that the confidence intervals are:
$$\hat{y} \pm t \cdot s \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x - \bar{x})^2}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2} }$$
and prediction bands:
$$\hat{y} \pm t \cdot s \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x - \bar{x})^2}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2} }$$
In the weighted linear regression case (weights $w_i$), we have the confidence intervals:
$$\hat{y} \pm t \cdot s \sqrt{ \frac{1}{\sum w_i} + \frac{(x - \bar{x}_w)^2}{\sum w_i (x_i - \bar{x}_w)^2} }$$
but what's the formula for the prediction bands? (in a similar form than the previous formula)
Intuitively, the bands should remain the same if we replace weights $1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots$ by, for example, $0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, \ldots$ so this shows it's probably not:
$$\hat{y} \pm t \cdot s \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{1}{\sum w_i} + \frac{(x - \bar{x}_w)^2}{\sum w_i (x_i - \bar{x}_w)^2}}$$
Goal: let's say we want, on a graph, to plot the $(x_i, y_i)$ scatter points, the weighted regression line, the confidence interval region and the prediction bands, like this:

then, which formula can we use to plot the prediction bands?

What is the origin of that intuition?  Because the weights are inverse variances (of the conditional responses), why do you suppose the bands ought to remain the same when you change those variances??

@whuber The weights are not always inverse variances / w_i = 1/s_i^2, we can imagine all kind of custom weights for a weighted linear regression, is that correct?

Yes, you can use "custom weights" -- but then what exactly would a prediction band tell you?  What would those weights mean?

Oh that's right @whuber! About my question, is my formula for prediction bands in the linear regression (without weights) correct? And what is the formula for prediction bands in the weighted case? Thanks in advance!

You can't obtain a formula without a probability model, and you haven't specified a probability model until you explain what the weights are intended to mean.  If they are inverse variances you can obtain one formula; if they are something else, then potentially different formulas (yielding different bands) would be appropriate.

@whuber The basic case I'm using is indeed weights = 1/s_i^2. What is the formula in this case? Thanks in advance!

Conceptually, it's the usual formula, which sums two independent variances: the variance of the estimated conditional mean plus the variance of the predicted value (that's where a specific weight for the predict value comes in).  Notice that you will need to know (or assume) the weight for the predicted value.

Thanks @whuber, can you just give the full formula (in math notation), so that I'm sure I'm using the exact formula?

It's already here on CV.  With a site search, I found a formula in mathematical notation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9669/919.

@whuber I'm totally familiar with linear algebra, but I don't do stats enough to do it with this abstraction. Can someone please just give the formula for prediction bands in weighted linear regression in a form similar to the formulas in my question? Thank you in advance!

It is counterproductive to attempt to re-express that matrix formula in any other way: it would be far too complicated.

I think some of the confusion stems from how different software interprets the weights. For example in R's lm if I pass a vector of weights all equal to .1 then I will get the exact same results (including intervals) as in the unweighted case, because I'm pretty sure the function normalizes the weights such that their mean is 1.

@ischmidt20 That's a useful remark, but not quite correct.  summary.lm will output "weighted" residuals that are inversely proportional to the roots of the weights. Moreover, predict.lm gives different prediction bands.  Here's an example with two sets of weights: set.seed(17); n <- 6; df <- data.frame(x = matrix(rnorm(2*n), n), y = rnorm(n)); df.new <- data.frame(x = matrix(rnorm(2*1), 1, 2)); w <- rexp(n); for (d in 0:1) {   print(summary(fit <- lm(y ~ ., df, weights = w * 10^(-d))));   print(predict(fit, df.new, interval = "prediction")) }

Not an answer. But perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my Bayesian tutorial (Ch. 11.4). You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65

Let's assume the data come from the following  heteroskedastic normal simple linear regression model, wherein the unit weights $w_i>0$ are known (even for future observations):
$$
y_i = \alpha+\beta x_i+\epsilon_i, \ \, \epsilon_i\sim N(0,w_i\sigma^2), \ \, \epsilon_i\perp x_i.
$$
The weighted least squares (WLS) estimators are then: $\hat{\beta}_W=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i(x_i-\bar{x}_W)(y_i-\bar{y}_W)}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i(x_i-\bar{x}_W)^2}$ and $\hat{\alpha}_W = \bar{y}_W-\hat{\beta}_W\bar{x}_W$, with $\bar{x}_W=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}$.
Given new observation $x_{n+1}$ and known weight $w_{n+1}>0$, we have that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{var}(\hat{y}_{n+1}\mid x_{n+1},w_{n+1}) =\operatorname{var}(\hat{\alpha}_W+\hat{\beta}_W x_{n+1}+\epsilon_{n+1}\mid x_{n+1},w_{n+1})\\
&\,= \operatorname{var}(\hat{\alpha}_W+\hat{\beta}_W x_{n+1}\mid x_{n+1},w_{n+1}) + \operatorname{var}(\epsilon_{n+1}\mid x_{n+1},w_{n+1})+0\\
&\,= \sigma^2\left(\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}+\frac{(x_{n+1}-\bar{x}_W)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i(x_i-\bar{x}_W)^2} \right) + w_{n+1}\sigma^2\\
&\,= \sigma^2\left(w_{n+1}+\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}+\frac{(x_{n+1}-\bar{x}_W)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i(x_i-\bar{x}_W)^2} \right). 
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, a prediction interval for $\hat{y}_{n+1}$ given $x_{n+1}$ and $w_{n+1}>0$ can be constructed as:
$$
\hat{\alpha}_W+\hat{\beta}_W x_{n+1}\mp t_{n-2}\hat{\sigma}_W\sqrt{w_{n+1}+\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}+\frac{(x_{n+1}-\bar{x}_W)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i(x_i-\bar{x}_W)^2}},
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}_W^2=\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^nw_i(\hat{\alpha}_W+\hat{\beta}_W x_{i}-y_i)^2$.

+1 As soon as I saw the emphasis on "known weight" I knew this was fundamentally a good answer.

Thank you @JohandeAguas. Let's say we want, on a graph, to plot the $(x_i, y_i)$ scatter points, the weighted regression line, the confidence interval region and the prediction bands, like this: https://i.sstatic.net/26YESe6M.png, then we don't have $w_{n+1}$, how would you plot the prediction bands?

I added this plot to the end of my question @JohandeAgua. Thanks a lot already for your answer which is great!

To visualize a pointwise prediction band within your sample, you interpolate the upper bound using $\hat{\alpha}W+\hat{\beta}W x{i} \boldsymbol{+} t{n-2}\hat{\sigma}W\sqrt{w{i}+\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}+\frac{(x_{i}-\bar{x}W)^2}{\sum{i=1}^n w_i(x_i-\bar{x}_W)^2}}$:
The lower bound can be calculated similarly but with a negative sign. For a simultaneous prediction band, an extra approach is required to control the family-wise error rate, such as using Bonferroni or Scheffé methods.

What is the most common way to display prediction bands @JohandeAguas, like in the plot graph I posted in the question, and which formula would you use to plot the dotted black curve? Thanks again!

Pointwise bands are simpler to compute and interpret, but they may not adequately cover the entire regression line since they are narrower and do not account for joint uncertainty. In contrast, simultaneous bands are generally wider and more complex to compute, with various methods available. However, they offer coverage guarantees, ensuring that the entire prediction function lies within the bands at the specified confidence level. The choice also depends on sample size and on how much you rely on uncertainty interpretation. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands
