# What is the exact difference between Prediction and Extrapolation?

Tags: prediction, interpolation

Apologies if the question is too trivial but what exactly sets these two apart?

Let's say that I have a set of data for a hundred points (the independent variable may not be uniformly spaced) as:

`{{1, 7}, {2, 8},...,{100, 5}}`

Now, I can apply any of the extrapolation techniques (Newton's, Lagrange's or even Curve Fitting for that matter) and get a `y = f(x)`. Now if I put in any `x`, in or out from my original data set, I can get the corresponding `y`. This way I predicted a `y` value which wasn't originally in my data set.

How is **Prediction** different from this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between estimation and prediction?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17773/what-is-the-difference-between-estimation-and-prediction)

Comment: @Carl Thank you for the flag: identifying duplicates takes effort and is always useful.  But that thread would be a duplicate only if extrapolation and estimation were the same thing, but they are not.

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolation is estimation of dependent values outside the range covered by the (independent) data the model has been fit to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation. It's not the same as interpolation, which is estimation between original data points. Prediction usually refers to future events, but in your context you could say (regarding the estimates) prediction is a hypernym of fitted values + interpolation + extrapolation.

Comment: I understand the difference between extra/interpolation but that's not my question. Can you elaborate more upon Extrapolation vs Prediction? Your current answer (last statement) isn't satisfactory enough.

Comment: There is no "vs". Extrapolation is prediction outside of the ranged covered by data, interpolation is prediction inside this range.

Comment: So `prediction` is just a term for saying `extrapolation & interpolation`. In other words, every prediction is either an extrapolation or an interpolation?

Comment: Basically. Although prediction refers to, well, prediction of future observations (which is important for estimation of uncertainties) whereas that's not necessarily the case for extrapolation and interpolation.

Comment: It is not clear to me that all predictive models extrapolate. E.g., time series analysis models based on well-informed and empirically backed data-generating processes, and dynamic empirical modeling methods, such as simplex projection, would seem to be interpolation-based, not extrapolation based.

Comment: To add to what @Alexis said, in spatial statistics interpolation and extrapolation are *both* considered to be prediction.  They are often distinguished by whether the support of the prediction (the x-values) lies within the convex hull of the data or not, respectively.  In one dimension that distinction comes down to whether the prediction is made for an x value within the data range or beyond it (in either direction).

Comment: @whuber Yes, one can call just about any statistical procedure a prediction, and that is misleading because it is often irrelevant or even wrong. The mean value of uniformly random integers from 1 to 6 is 3.5, which is not closed for integers, so 3.5 is a wrong prediction. A least error prediction from OLS in y predicts an equation that is wrong for bivariate data, but it offers a least error of "predicting" y given x. More accurately, it is an observed least error mapping of x to y.  One can call any probability a "prediction," but more accurately it is a post hoc observation.

Comment: @Carl You misread my comments and misuse the terms.  I have explicitly distinguished estimation from prediction.  Guessing the value of a random variable is not merely a matter of estimating a probability related to its distribution.  For details, please [read our thread on this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17773).

Comment: @whuber In your answer, that you refer to above, you state, "a predictor usually has larger uncertainty than a related estimator" I do not agree. OLS in y has less error of prediction of y given x and a higher R$^2$ than a bivariate estimating equation, which has better accuracy if the data is indeed bivariate. A bivariate estimating equation is not a least error predictor, the thing "predicted" is the bivariate equation, and is useful, for example, in clinical laboratories to replace test A with test B. It seems to me you are misusing terms by lumping different things into the same terms.

Comment: @Carl I invite you to look up these terms in any reputable textbook.

Comment: @whuber OK, This is more or less what I am using: From https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3792  "Definition:
In general, prediction is the process of determining the magnitude of statistical variates at some future point of time. In statistical contexts the word may also occur in slightly different meanings; e.g. in a regression equation expressing a dependent variate y in terms of dependent x’s, the value given for y by specified values of x’s is called the “predicted” value even when no temporal element is involved." What are you using?

Comment: @Carl I avoid the econometric literature like that link, which employs some terminology narrowly (everything seems to revolve around time series), and rely on classic statistics texts like Hahn & Meeker, *Statistical Intervals* section 1.2, Wasserman's *All of Statistics* (especially exercise 13.10), or *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics,* Volume 2, Fifth Edition, sections 28.9 - 28.12. I first learned of the distinctions between estimation and prediction in the spatial statistics literature, where that concept is fundamental and the "future" isn't around to confuse people.

Comment: @whuber I think you have a point but I feel like I am shadow-boxing. This is really another question even more nitty-gritty than what the OP asked here, and this text is not really helping anyone. Therefore, let us move this to a discussion on it own merit. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599212/what-exactly-does-prediction-mean-in-best-statistical-terms-and-when-is-it-inapp

Answer (score -2):

The explanation is excellent, however, the casual association of the term prediction to future events may have been too subtle. In other words, I don't know that the implied other part of that explanation was derived. Prediction = future event, estimation = not necessarily future, i.e. fitted value, can be inferential (established population).

Comment: In statistics, "prediction" does not necessarily involve any concept of time.  It means to guess the value of a random variable.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17773.  In contrast, "estimation" means to guess the value of a parameter (usually considered non-random).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/336063)