# Is a confidence interval a prediction interval for the sample mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, prediction-interval, mean

I am learning about different intervals and trying to get my head around them.

Given that a sample mean from a sample size $n$ has a pdf equal to $f(x)$, the 95% prediction interval [a,b] is an interval is the region where there is a 95% chance of observing the next sample mean. This satisfies $\int_a^b f(x) dx= 0.95$

The 95% confidence interval [u,v] is a region where 95% of the future sample means would lie in. This satisfies $\int_u^v f(x) dx= 0.95$

The equations for both are the same but I'm not sure if they are conceptually equal. Could someone please explain this in more detail?

Comment: That is not the standard definition of a $95\%$ confidence interval, which is more along the lines of applying the same methodology to repeated independent sample means with the same sample size, $95\%$ of the confidence intervals so constructed would include the population mean.  I also have doubts about your description of the prediction interval, which does not seem to depend on the actual value of the sample mean observed. A difference is that the prediction interval takes account of the uncertainty of the next sample mean compared with the population mean, in addition to this sample's.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-prediction-intervals for more