# Confidence Versus Prediction Intervals using Quantile Regression / Quantile Loss Function

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval, quantile-regression

If you fit a quantile regression for the 5th and 95th percentile this is often described as an estimate of a 90% **prediction** interval. This is the most prevalent it seems in the machine learning domain where [random forests](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume7/meinshausen06a/meinshausen06a.pdf) has been adapted to predict the quantiles of each leaf node or [GBM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_quantile.html) with a quantile loss function.

Is this best characterized as a confidence or prediction interval and why?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After posting this I realized it is most accurately called a confidence interval, regardless of the terminology used by sci-kit learn.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3885826/

"However, it must be kept in mind that the resulting confidence intervals are a model approximation rather than true statistics".

Comment: Most "accurately" called?  No.  Most commonly?  Probably.  Take a look at the documentation for the *‘randomUniformForest* **R** package, which has a "confInt" type for the *predict* method which yields, according to the manual pages, *prediction intervals*.  So there appears to be widespread confusion between the two concepts (see also the reference I gave in my main answer).  I'm going to stick to my guns -- the correct terminology is **prediction interval** for **data** and confidence interval for a parameter -- but it looks like very few people will care if you get it wrong.

Comment: Sorry but that is not correct. Confidence intervals are intervals around expected values such as E(y|X) while prediction intervals are intervals around y|X. See this  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-prediction-intervals

Comment: Yes, CI's are for E(Y|x), PI's for Y|x, but in the Meinshausen paper it is the latter case that we're looking at.  Quote: "Prediction Intervals
How reliable is a prediction for a new instance?".  The new instance is Y, given explanatory variables x.  The author goes on: "a new observation of Y, for X=x, is with high probability in the interval I(x)".  This is a statement about Y itself, not the mean of all possible Y, given x.  If you are asking in your original question if Meinshausen is using the wrong terminology then I remain quite sure that he is not.

Comment: I appreciate where you are coming from B_miner, I had the same "second thoughts" about this but I think the easiest thing to consider is that quantile regression (irrelevant of the algorithm for a moment) is a different approach to constructing prediction intervals as it indeed estimates conditional quantile functions from the available data. If we fit the conditional quantile function at the 2.5% and 97.5% levels we can obtain prediction intervals for "nominal" 95% coverage from the corresponding interval.

Answer (score 15):

Definitely a prediction interval, see for example [here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/intervals/).

Quantile regression for the $5^\textrm{th}$ and $95^\textrm{th}$ quantiles attempts to find bounds $y_0({\bf x})$ and $y_1({\bf x})$, on the response variable $y$ given predictor variables ${\bf x}$, such that
$$
  \mathbb{P}\left(Y\le y_0({\bf X})\right)=0.05 \\
  \mathbb{P}\left(Y\le y_1({\bf X})\right)=0.95
$$
so
$$
  \mathbb{P}\left(\,y_0({\bf X})\le Y\le y_1({\bf X})\,\right)\ =\ 0.90
$$
which is by definition a $90\%$ prediction interval.

A $90\%$ prediction interval should contain (as-yet-unseen) new **data** $90\%$ of the time.  In contrast, a $90\%$ confidence interval for some **parameter** (e.g. the mean) should contain the true mean unless we were unlucky to the tune of 1-in-10 in the data used to construct the interval.