# Why Confidence Interval is always wider than Prediction interval?

Tags: regression, self-study, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

I was given a problem asking that and I'm not quite sure how to answer it. If anyone can please explain me

Comment: Since it seems to be a homework, please add `[self-study]` tag and check  http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Prediction intervals are actually always wider than confidence intervals. A detailed explantion is given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/271232/180467

Answer (score 7):

Is it?

> I have seen someone compute a confidence interval for the mean, and
>   use it as if it was a prediction interval for a future observation.
>   The trouble is, confidence intervals for the mean are *much* narrower
>   than prediction intervals, and so this gave him an exaggerated and
>   false sense of the accuracy of his forecasts. Instead of the interval
>   containing 95% of the probability space for the future observation, it
>   contained only about 20%.

(source http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/intervals/)

Comment: Also: https://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1506/

Answer (score 5):

I can be very, very confident what the average age of a United States citizen is if I've taken enough samples. But if you pick a person at random, I basically have no idea how old they are. One has almost nothing to do with the other.

Comment: Variance of sample mean vs variance of population.  Is this what the op was asking?

Comment: @innisfree That's pretty much what it comes down to.