# What's WRONG with my multiple regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spss

I am working on a regression model, more precisely, multiple regression model for predicting one single value. I have a dataset of cars and some technical data.

For example, I have the following prediction for the following car data:

```
Make: Volvo 
Model: XC90 T8 Recharge AWD 
Doors: 4 
Seats: 7 
SeatsMin: 7 
SeatsMax: 7 
Dimensions: 4950x1931x1776 
Length: 4950 
Width: 1931 
Height: 1776 
WheelBase: 2984 
Weight: 2320 
MaxWeight: 2980 
TrunkVolMin: 262 
TrunkVolMax: 1816 
TankVolume: 70 
Electric: Electric or hybrid 
TurboCharged: 1: Turbo charged engine 
Kompressor: 1: Kompressor charged engine 
Displacement: 1969 
EnginePower: 288(390)/6000 
EngineTorque: 640/2200 
MaxPower: 288.00 
MaxTorque: 640.00 
Druve: All wheel drive 
FrontWheelDrive: Front wheel drive 
RearWheelDrive: Rear wheel drive 
Gears: 8 
Automatic: Automatic gearbox 
Acceleration: 5.8 
MaxSpeed: 180 
FuelConsumption: 2.1 S 
CO2: 57 
FuelType: S 
Predicted_Acceleration: 5.66731 
Residuals: .13269
```

Acceleration by default is **5.8**, the model gives **5.66731**, meaning it is off by **0.1** or something. According to the model summary, $R^2$ is roughly **75.9%** percent accurate.

[image]

**EDIT:** *I do not know for sure, what other bits of data here can be used to form a more accurate model. I haven't made any dummy variables yet. Not decoded into binary.*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No, but, what is my model missing? To become more accurate. I have plenty of data, but, I use the following only: **MaxTorque**, **MaxWeight**, and **Gears**

Comment: What do you mean by "more accurate"?

Comment: Well, for another car in my list, the original value for acceleration is **9.9**, but my model predicts and outputs: **10.71069**, this is not accurate. Now, I am not good with cars, so I do not know exactly what parts of the data here can help achieve better output.

Comment: Why is $10.71069$ not accurate but $5.66731$ is? Both times, the wrong number is predicted.

Comment: Neither is accurate. This is the issue.

Comment: I am using the following variables: **MaxTorque**, **MaxWeight,** and **Gears** found in the data above. I am not considering potential interactions, nor decoding values into binary form (dummy variables).

Comment: A model can never (unless it is overspecified) predict *exactly* the correct values. In this particular case, the predictions seem to be surprisingly accurate when the simplicity of the model is taken into account: your two examples have relative errors of 2% and 8%, respectively. Please explain what you mean by "accurate".

Answer (score 11):

Your comment **"Now, I am not good with cars, so I do not know exactly what parts of the data here can help achieve better output"** is very insightful! You've correctly identified your problem, and the solution is not in the data or the model. The solution is finding out more about how cars accelerate.

I would advise you to find someone who does know a lot about cars, and ask them a lot of questions. You might learn things like:

- "Turbo charged engines always accelerate faster/slower than Kompressor charged engines"
- "If you want a car that accelerates fast, you would look for XXX and YYY but avoid ZZZ"
  (You would then know to include those things in your model)
- "XXX increases acceleration up to a point but then levels off"
  (Maybe you would then include XXX in your model as a polynomial term instead of a linear term)
- "For a front wheel drive car XXX is important but for a rear-wheel drive car XXX makes no difference"
  (Then you might include an interaction term in your model)
- "Error of 0.8 is really close, that's very good accuracy" or "Error of 0.8 is really big, that's terrible accuracy"
  (Then you would know how useful your model actually is)

I also do not know anything about cars, so I can't answer these questions. They may not even be the right questions! But for a real-world modelling task, understanding the real-world meaning of the data is never time wasted.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your question is, especially as the prediction looks amazingly accurate to me: 5.67 versus 5.8 is just an error of about 2%. Maybe you are misinterpreting the reported value of $R^2$ as a measure for accuracy, which it is not.

A nice thing about linear models is that they also estimate the accuracy of the prediction by means of a "prediction interval"*). It estimates, under the assumption that the model is correct, an interval in which the response value will be observed 95% of the times for the given predictor values. In R, e.g., you can obtain it with

```
predict(model, data.frame(x1=val1, x2=val2, 
          ...), interval="predict")
```

This way, you can estimate the accuracy of the prediction even when the true value is unknown.

*) Edit: in the original version of the answer, I called the "prediction interval" a "confidence interval", but as pointed out by @whuber, this term is reserved for parameter estimates.

Comment: Confidence interval or prediction interval?

Comment: That code produces a *prediction interval.*  It differs from a confidence interval of the predicted value in that it is widened to accommodate the (independent) uncertainty inherent in the unobserved value itself.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493.

Comment: I guess, by "confidence interval", you mean the confidence interval for the *mean* value of the prediction, not for the prediction. This is returned with the parameter `interval="confidence"`. While this is the usual linear model lingo, a 95% interval for the actual observed response ("prediction interval") is a "confidence interval", too, albeit for a different observable.

Comment: The link I gave explains the sense in which prediction intervals are *not* confidence intervals of any kind.  A prediction interval tries to bracket a *random variable* whereas a confidence interval tries to bracket a (nonrandom) *parameter.*

Comment: @whuber Thanks for clarifying terms. I have edited the answer and used the term "prediction interval" insetead.