# Is it possible to calculate prediction interval without info on the predictor x?

Tags: regression, linear, prediction-interval

I can see from [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/3/3.3) that prediction interval for a new response Y (setting is simple linear regression) is

[image]

However I've read [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prediction-intervals-for-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=A%20prediction%20interval%20is%20calculated,estimate%20the%20prediction%20interval%20directly.) that

[image]

Apparently, no calculation related to x is needed according to this last formula. I would like to know if I can use this formula to calculate prediction intervals and if it is based on some hypothesis to be valid.

Comment: "yhat" refers to the value predicted by the model when the explanatory variable is set to "x".

Comment: I know. The part I don't know is how I can calculate the expression involving x as shown in the first formula?

Comment: Am I correct to say that the second formula assumes that the "x" part is negligible (as well as the 1/n) ?

Comment: No.  It's just a sloppy formula.  At the very least it should write "$\hat y(x)$" instead of "$\hat y$" ("yhat").

Comment: I understand but how can I calculate the "x" part, the sum of squared deviations of x from mean(x) ?

Comment: ?? The formula is explicit.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear in my post but from what I understand of the "sloppy" formula is that we don't have the x's, only the y's (output of the model: ground truth and estimation). So my question was: without the x's, how can one calculate the 'x' part ?

Comment: You can't.  Indeed, that statistic (the variance of the x's) is usually not included in publications.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying that the first formula shown above for a prediction interval includes a part involving x but usually we don't include it because it's negligible? I cannot find a place which does not include it (ex: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-prediction-intervals)

Comment: I am not saying anything like that.  The first formula is clear and correct.  The second formula is a vague shorthand intended to be equivalent to the first.  In order to apply either, you need the equivalent of the prediction point $x_h,$ the mean of the data values $\bar x,$ the sum of squares of the residuals $\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2,$ the data count $n,$ the MSE, and the confidence $1-\alpha.$ None of those can be determined from the others.