# Estimate overall descriptive statistics (such as mean, Std, CI ) for 100 resampling with same sample size and same population

Tags: descriptive-statistics, resampling

I have a sample of data with n=200 and I would like to predict my descriptive statistics such as mean, Std Dev and 95% CI when I have specific sample size for example n=10 based on the current study.
I assumed my population follows the Normal distribution and I applied t test to  calculate CI.
What I have done, I applied random sampling with replacement with n=10 from the original sample and repeated the process 100 times and calculated the mean of each 100 samples then calculate the **mean(100 means), sd(100 means) then 95%CI(100 means)** to get a good prediction of descriptive statistics for any random sample with size n=10. I was wondering if this approach is correct or not?
Or the other solution could be to get the **mean(100 means) and Pooled.Sd(100 sd)** then calculate 95%CI.
Could you please give me advise?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Ordinarily, when we estimate something it is a property of a postulated underlying distribution.  A "descriptive statistic" is something else altogether: it's a mathematical function of data.  It appears you are trying to determine something about statistics of smaller samples, but even then the question is ambiguous: are you trying to ask about how those statistics vary *among all possible samples* or only how they vary *among all possible subsamples of the data?*  Regardless, the applicability of a CI here is unclear, so please spell out what you mean by that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My main question is what would be the best estimation of mean and Std Dev and 95% CI for any new sample with size n (=10)  based on the current study and data (N=200?

Comment: The best estimate to use for any future sample is the best estimate for the population.  The CI is not estimated, because it is not a property of the population: as a property of a new sample, it is a *prediction.*  Maybe it would be helpful to review this distinction: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493 for instance.  If you really do want to predict a CI, then the answer depends on what specific procedure to compute a CI you are using as well as the assumptions you make about the population, so please include that information in your post.

Comment: Yes, I want to predict CI for new sample size (n=10), and as I assumed the population follows the normal distribution and I used t.test for calculating new CI.

Comment: Good--that's clear now.  Please edit your post to reflect those details.

Comment: Thanks, I have added...