# Problem in computing the Variance of Regression Estimator

Tags: regression, variance, regression-coefficients

Referring to the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9144/46297), my doubt is regarding the actual computation of variance of the forecast. The variance depicted here is $\sigma^2 [1+X^*(X'X)^{-1}(X^*)']$. As mentioned in the link added here, if $X$ is a row vector, then $X'X$ will be a singular matrix whose inverse blows up to very large values. My $X$ values are highly deterministic and are readily available without any error. Is there any way to make this inversion possible so that we can actually compute the variance?

Comment: In this context it is commonly understood that $\left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1}$ is a *generalized inverse* (or, more accurately, a [constrained pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott%E2%80%93Duffin_inverse)); that is, 
$\left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1} X^{*\prime}$ refers to any solution $\hat{\beta^\prime}$ of the equation $X^\prime X \hat{\beta^\prime} = X^{*\prime}.$  The value of $X^{*}\hat{\beta^\prime}$ is well defined if and only if $X^{*\prime}$ lies within the span of the rows of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{X}$ a row vector? If you regression is $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}+\mathbf{e}$, i.e. $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\cdots+\beta_kx_k+e_i$, $\mathbf{X}$ can be a row vector only if you have a single observation. If $\mathbf{X}$ is a full rank matrix of dimension $N\times K$, $N>K$, then $\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X}$ is not singular.

$\mathbf{X}^*$ can be, and often is, a row vector such that
$$\sigma^2[1+\underset{1\times 1}{\underbrace{\underset{1\times K}{\mathbf{X}^*}\;\underset{K\times K}{\underbrace{(\underset{K\times N}{\mathbf{X}'}\underset{N\times K}{\mathbf{X}})}}^{-1}\;\underset{K\times 1}{(\mathbf{X}^*)'}}}]=\sigma^2[1+scalar]$$

Comment: The point of the question is that when $X$ is *not* of full rank, then the inverse of $X^\prime X$ is not defined.

Comment: @whuber in the OP I read "if $X$ is a row vector, then $X′X$ will be a singular matrix", which is right because $X$ must be full _column_ rank. But if $X$ is a row vector (not the null vector) then it _is_ full rank: $rk(X)=1$ and could never be $>1$.

Comment: But that last remark is irrelevant: your formulas are still undefined unless the *column* rank of $X$ is maximal.

Comment: @whuber please, don't be lazy and read again ;-) I've written: "if $X$ is a full rank matrix of dimension $N\times K$, $N>K$" etc. and that means $rk(X)=K$, i.e. my formula _is_ defined. Please.

Comment: Sergio, the question concerns the case where $X$ is *not* a "full rank matrix", so my concern is that your answer misses the point. Whether I am correct or not, do **not** accuse me, or anyone else on this site, of being "lazy" in order to make your point or advance an argument: such writing is offensive and not accepted on this site. Before you do anything else on SE, please visit our [help] at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/behavior and read it thoroughly.

Comment: @wuber the question concerns the case _where $X$ is a row vector_ (always full rank if not the null vector), _not_ where $X$ is not a "full rank matrix". So _you_ are missing the point. Why do _you_ accuse me? Why don't you give _your_ answer instead of accusing me?

Comment: When $X$ is a row vector of dimension $N$, the issue before us concerns inverting $X^\prime X$, which is a rank-$1$ $N\times N$ matrix. The O.P. observes that the inverse does not exist in this case (at least when $N\gt 1$). Depending on what you really mean by "full rank matrix," either your answer does not address this situation or it incorrectly asserts that $X^\prime X$ is invertible. I accuse *you* of nothing but I am concerned about the relevance and correctness of the *reply* you have posted, that's all.

Comment: Not at all. The OP observes that the inverse does not exist when $X$ is $1\times K$ (why $N$?), and this is right. He misses that __in the linked post__ the row vector is $X^*$, not $X$: "Let $X^∗$ be a row vector containing the values of the predictors for the forecasts" etc. Please notice that $X^*(X'X)^{-1}(X^*)'$ _is not defined_ if the row vector is of dimension $N$, because $(X'X)^{-1}$ is of dimension $K\times K$. The OP is about a row vector of dimension $K$, not $N$. The OP is about the _variance of the forecast_. Can you see what you've missed?

Comment: I think you and I are using $K$ and $N$ differently; I apologize for not being consistent with your usage, but I see no error or ambiguity in what I wrote. I also agree that one possible interpretation of the question is that the O.P. has confused $X^{*}$ with $X$. But if that is your interpretation, *then please edit your answer to make it clear that is the point you are addressing.* Once more--for the last time--I request that you cease from attacking me personally and stick with the issues.

Comment: I'll edit my answer if someone else agrees with you, because I can't conceive any other interpretation. BTW: if saying "you've missed the point" is attacking, that's what you've done again and again. Asking instead of asserting would be more polite. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14781/discussion-between-whuber-and-sergio).

Comment: I can't see why. Sorry.