# Regression Confidence interval in terms of standard errors of the parameters

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval

In simple linear regression, I know the confidence interval can be calculated from:

$CI = t\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{(x-\bar{x})^2\sigma^2}{\sum{(x-\bar{x})^2}}}$

I know this equation comes from the relation $Y=\bar{Y} +\beta_1(x-\bar{x})$

Is there a way to either use Matrix Algebra to calculate this from the Standard Error matrix?

$\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$ where $\sigma^2 = \frac{SS_e}{\nu}$ and degrees of freedom $\nu = n-2$

I'm looking for a way to extend the confidence interval to multiple linear regression, including polynomial x.

Comment: Didn't you find anything when searching our site?  Try [multiple regression confidence interval](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+regression+confidence+interval)

Comment: I see lots of R code, but no generalizations.

Comment: Here's the closest I could come in my search: Rob Hyndman's formula for a prediction interval at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9144/919.  A value of $1$ is mysteriously added in--that accounts for the prediction uncertainty.  If you were to leave that out, you would have a confidence interval.  For details, consult any textbook on multiple regression.

Comment: It's not mysterious, the prediction interval has an extra 1 to account for the fact the we are predicting future values of $Y$, vs the value of $\hat{Y}$ in the confidence interval. Something like: $V(Y) = V(\hat{Y}) + \sigma^2$

Comment: Isn't that what I wrote? :-)  But since you clearly understand that point, you will be able to use Hyndman's post effectively.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the equation I was looking for, go ahead and post it below if you would like.