# Question about confidence intervals and prediction intervals

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, variance, standard-error, prediction-interval

Considering following linear multiple regression model:
\begin{equation}
y=X\beta + e,
\end{equation}
where observations $y\in\Re^n$, coefficents $\beta\in\Re^p$ and $e\sim N(0,\sigma I)$ is a white Gaussian noise term.

By the definition of the confidence interval:
\begin{equation}
\hat{y} \pm t_{n-p}^{\alpha/2} \times \mathrm{SE}_\bar{y}
\end{equation}
where $t_{n-p}^{\alpha/2}$ is the critical value, and standard error
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{SE}_\bar{y} = \frac{\sigma_y}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{equation}
I understand that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\beta})=\hat{\sigma}^2 (X^\top X)^{-1} \qquad\text{and} \qquad \mathrm{Var}(\hat{y}_{n+1})=\mathrm{Var}(x_{n+1}\hat{\beta})=\hat{\sigma}^2x_{n+1}^\top(X^\top X)^{-1}x_{n+1}
\end{equation}
My question is that why in post:[Difference between confidence intervals and prediction intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-prediction-intervals)
and
[Obtaining a formula for prediction limits in a linear model (i.e.: prediction intervals)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9131/obtaining-a-formula-for-prediction-limits-in-a-linear-model-i-e-prediction-in)
they use square root of Variance
\begin{equation}
\hat{y}_{n+1} \pm t_{n-p}^{\alpha/2} \times \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(\hat{y}_{n+1})}
\end{equation}
rather than the standard error?? Where is the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: It might help to distinguish *formulas* from definitions.  The definitions provide insight, whereas the formulas (as you give here) are only that: formulas.

Comment: Hi: Are you sure you mean $\hat{y}$ for the first two formulae where you define CI and standard error. I think you mean $\hat{\beta_{i}}$, a particular element of the estimate of the $\beta$ vector ? If you do mean $\hat{y}$, then I've never seen such a formula ?